# Run one method in multiple threads as decided by the system

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I have a method that processeswords in two lists, a priority list and a standard list.

```
ConcurrentBag<Word> PriorityWords = ...;
ConcurrentBag<Word> UnprocessedWords = ...;

public void ProcessAllWords()
{
    while (true)
    {
        Word word = SelectWordToProcess();
        if (word == null) break;
        ProcessWord(word);
    }
}

private Word SelectWordToProcess()
{
    Word word;
    if (PriorityWords.TryTake(out word) || UnprocessedWords.TryTake(out word))
        return word;
    else
        return null;
}

public void ProcessWord(Word word) { ... }
```

I want to run this method on multiple cores.  Currently, I simply open one thread per processor:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Environment.ProcessorCount; i++)
{
    new Thread(ProcessAllWords).Start();
}
```

Is there a more suitable way that lets the system decide how many threads to open based on current system performance, similar to `Parallel.ForEach()`?

---

**EDIT:** More detail on the application.

The word list is prepopulated with ~180,000 words and every word is to be permutated with every other word.  `ProcessAllWords` is an O(n²) operation.  The threads will all run flat-out until all words are processed, then terminate.  While the threads are running, I can asynchronously give priority to specific words by adding them to the `PriorityWords` list.  Initial tests show my system processes about 5 words/sec, so that's 10 hours of 100% CPU processing.

Comment: How do you guide the threads to the corresponding cores? They might all be started in the same core.

Comment: You want to slow down your processing if the system is too busy? If you don't have a lots of words or they arrive at a reasonnable rate your threads will pass most of the time waiting, so not consuming any CPU resource.

Comment: @Maarten: I don't guide the threads. I just hope for the best. That's the simplest solution I have so far and I'm searching for a better one.

Comment: Your synchronization plumbing seems correct and does not explain why you have such a low throughput. So the issue is in **ProcessWord**: if it's a CPU intensive task then there is little you can do except optimize it. So could you show use its code, maybe we can help.

Comment: @Pragmateek: The question isn't about speed, but about responsible and effective use of multiple cores to process a set of data.  Any issue with the speed of `ProcessWord` is a separate question.  This is a learning exercise for me.

Comment: So as said above your multithreading plumbing is good and you probably won't gain anything by changing it. So if your cores are at 100% due to *ProcessWord* then you've done your best. If you want hard numbers you can profile your code to find the bottlenecks, but again it will probably be *ProcessWord*. :) And keep in mind that you should optimize what takes 99% of the time not what takes 1% because at best you will gain 1% speedup vs x100 speedup. :)

Comment: What else is running on the computer at the same time?  You might want to leave 1 core free to do other things.

Answer (score 1):

Your method of starting Environment.ProcessorCount threads is good. The Task Parallel Library will do the automatic scheduling that you're looking for, but at the cost of over subscribing your CPU. This will decrease the responsiveness of your application to priority words.

As for the various methods of using TPL, parallel for and task factory will both queue up a bunch of words, making it very unresponsive to priority. You can maintain your priority with a generator method and PLINQ, but then you get a fixed number of threads as you have now. You can either set your thread count or use the default of 2xEnvironment.ProcessorCount. All in all, since your task is CPU bound, I would keep your current implementation.